# self.performSegue cannot find storyboard-segue-ID even though it has been named

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode4

I am trying to programmatically segue in `LiveController.swift`. The relevant bit of code is here in `LiveController.swift`

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"openWelcomePage" ,sender:self)
```

which throws error:

```
2020-04-16 20:51:44.614413-0400 alpha[53206:2805423] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<alpha.LiveController: 0x101c248c0>) has no segue with identifier 'openWelcomePage''
```

This indicates the segue has not been named. But it has:

[image]

The over all storyboard is here:[image]

Note the highlighted `NavigationController` is the source, it embeds `Live` which is attached to `LiveController.swift`. The target of the segue is the page with `Log in` and `Sign up`.

Note when I put a button into `LiveController` and drag a segue from the button to the `Welcome` view, and name it `buttonSegue`:

```
 self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"buttonSegue" ,sender:self)
```

displays the page modally as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the segue from LiveController, not from Navigation Controller

Comment: so this snippet `self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"buttonSegue" ,sender:self)` is in LIveController. But I cannot drag a segue from the corresponding view to LiveController in Storyboard to the login page, because xcode wont allow me.

Comment: do you control+drag it from the yellow circle on top off LiveViewController to LoginPage?

https://www.techotopia.com/images/b/b2/Xcode_8_storyboard_new_project.png

Answer (score 0):

This could be a few things so try these fixes:

1. Clean and build your project. Then, run again.
2. Quit Xcode, open up project and run.
3. In the `Attribute Inspector`, remove `openWelcomePage` and leave it blank.

Hope that either of these suggestions help.

Comment: I did all of that except 3. If I remove `openWelcomePage`, then how should  I reference it? To clarify, in production there wouldn't be a button that segues to WelcomePage. I just wanted to show that you can segue from a button, but no programmatically.

Comment: The `openWelcomePage` identifier that appears on the `Attribute Inspector` references the string you put in `performSegue`. I hope that answers your question.

Comment: could you clarify? In self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"foo" ,sender:self), what should "foo" be if not the name of the segue object it self? Do I use the Storyboard ID of the target?

Comment: Of course. Sorry for the confusion. `self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"openWelcomePage" ,sender:self)` is just fine. What I think you should do is in the image you provided with the first two words being `Storyboard Segue`, remove `openWelcomePage` in `Selector`.

Comment: Also, try removing the storyboard segue (`openWelcomePage`) and attaching it again to the view you are going to segue into.

Comment: Yup I did that and it still failed. Just to clarify, I dragged the segue from Navigation Controller to the target. Not from the view embedded inside the Navigation Controller. Could it be that "openWelcomePage" segue is not in scope inside the embedded controller?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211845/discussion-between-chibro2-and-mat).